# Flask: Getting an AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute

Tags: python, flask

In my flask application, under the create_app function, I am assigning a value to ***g.client*** :

```
with app.app_context():
        g.client = GraphqlClient(endpoint=app.config['AMT_GRAPHQL'])
```

My folder structure is:

```
/app
   __init__.py
   /agents
       __init__.py
       grequests.py
```

Under my ***agents/**init**.py***  I have initialized blueprints and I have one route which is calling a function situated under ***agents/grequests.py***

***agents/**init**.py:***

```
from flask import Blueprint
from .grequests import *
bp = Blueprint('agents', __name__, url_prefix='/agents')
@bp.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def allAgents():
    agents = getAllAgents()
    return agents
```

***agents/grequests.py:***

```
from flask import g
from python_graphql_client import GraphqlClient
def getAllAgents():
    # Create the query string to get all agents
    query = """
        query {
            allAgents {
                edges {
                    node {
                        firstName
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    """
    return g.client.execute(query=query)
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'client'
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Don't have much idea about what this `g` is. But as per your error whatever the `g` object is, it don't have any `client` attribute. Maybe it's a typo or name of attribute is something else.

Comment: g is a global namespace for holding any data you want during a single app context. For example, a before_request handler could set g.user, which will be accessible to the route and other functions. You will need a different approach in executing your query

Comment: Object g has no attribute Client declared.

Comment: You can do a membership check by using the `in` operator or calling the `get()` method, which will return None (or an alternative default) if not present.